# Cant access path

Tags: c#, path

```
VideoDownloader downloader = new VideoDownloader(video: videoInfo, savePath: Application.StartupPath);
```

Access for the path is denied, I tried to rebuilt solution but didnt work.
What am I wrong with?

Comment: My guess is that your app doesnt have permission to write to that folder.  Been like that for many years thru many Windows versions

Comment: if so it doesnt have access to any folder? Ive tried other folders

Comment: How could we possibly know how permissions are set up on your computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use the property:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Depending on how/who launch your application or if it comes from ClickOne, the response folder could be a private folder or a system folder where you don't have permissions. You have more details about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).